# Преобразование pd.df (merge, groupby, pivot_table, dates)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть 2 df. a и b.

```
print(a)

              id              date         
0           2155759        2017-12-22        
1           2155983        2018-03-20                  
2           2156242        2018-02-07
```

и

```
print (b)

             id            date                  type
0           2155759  2017-12-22 18:30:22.767       2
1           2155759  2017-12-22 18:31:28.577       2
2           2155983  2018-02-06 13:19:57.917      11
3           2155983  2018-03-20 13:20:15.813      11
4           2155983  2018-03-20 13:45:33.940      11
5           2155983  2018-03-20 13:38:37.857      11
6           2155983  2018-03-20 13:52:51.590       3
7           2155983  2018-03-20 13:45:10.423       3
8           2155983  2018-03-20 13:32:14.243       2
9           2155983  2018-03-20 13:32:41.967       3
10          2156242  2018-02-07 10:51:54.983       2
```

в результате преобразований должен получиться 3й df:

```
print(c)

                  id              date        2      3      11    
    0           2155759        2017-12-22     2      Nan    Nan
    1           2155983        2018-03-20     1       3      3
    2           2156242        2018-02-07     1      Nan    Nan
```

**Преобразования:**
Нужно подтянуть сводную таблицу с количеством type по каждому id, из 'b', к df 'а'. Объединение должно быть по полю id из df 'a'.

**НО:**
Сводная таблица, по df 'b', должна включать в себя только те строки, в которых date совпадает  с date из df 'a', по одному и тому же id (по этой причине при создании сводной таблицы ,из df 'b', была отброшена строка с индексом 2)

Требуется помощь в выполнении этих действий.

Смог сделать только сводную таблицу, без учета условий с датами:

```
b = b.pivot_table(index='id', columns='type', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
b = b['date'].reset_index()
```

**Ссылка на таблицы:**
https://yadi.sk/d/AI8SIA7OdE1NRQ

Comment: Откуда взялось значение `1` в столбце `2` для `id=2156243` в результирующем DF?

Comment: накосячил, пока примеры составлял, исправил)

Comment: `2156242 != 2156142` и даты тоже не совпадают... ;-)

Comment: ну сейчас то точно поправил!
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = (b.assign(date=b["date"].dt.floor("D"))
        .merge(a)
        .pivot_table(index=["id","date"], columns="type", 
                     values="type", aggfunc='size'))
```

результат:

```
In [22]: res
Out[22]:
type                 2    3    11
id      date
2155759 2017-12-22  2.0  NaN  NaN
2155983 2018-03-20  1.0  3.0  3.0
2156242 2018-02-07  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

---

С выложенными данными:

```
In [182]: a = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\a.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=['Dateinput'])

In [183]: b = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\b.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=['Dateinput'])

In [184]: res = (b.assign(Dateinput=b["Dateinput"].dt.floor("D"))
     ...:         .merge(a.assign(Dateinput=a["Dateinput"].dt.floor("D")))
     ...:         .pivot_table(index=["Idclient","Dateinput"], columns="i_type",
     ...:                      values="i_type", aggfunc='size'))

In [185]: res
Out[185]:
i_type                0   1    2    3    10   11  20   30  31   40
Idclient Dateinput
2147787  2017-12-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
2149318  2018-03-13  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
2149469  2018-03-12  1.0 NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
2149963  2018-02-13  1.0 NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
2151182  2018-03-22  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  2.0 NaN  NaN
2152629  2018-01-04  1.0 NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0
2152765  2017-12-03  NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
2153216  2018-02-01  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
2154339  2018-02-10  1.0 NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
2154460  2018-02-28  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
...                  ...  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ...  ..  ...
3148755  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
3148757  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
3148764  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  3.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
3148765  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
3148773  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
3148774  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  2.0 NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
3148777  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
3148781  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
3148794  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
3148801  2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  3.0  1.0  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN

[21401 rows x 10 columns]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
res = a.merge((a.assign(Dateinput=a["Dateinput"].dt.floor("D"))
                .merge(b.assign(Dateinput=b["Dateinput"].dt.floor("D")))
                .pivot_table(index=["Idclient","Dateinput"], columns="i_type", 
                             values="i_type", aggfunc="nunique")),
               on="Idclient", how="left")
```

результат:

```
In [283]: res
Out[283]:
       Idclient  Dateinput    0   1    2    3   10   11  20   30  31   40
0       2147787 2017-12-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
1       2149318 2018-03-13  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
2       2149963 2018-02-13  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
3       2150046 2017-12-14  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
4       2150846 2018-01-16  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
5       2152765 2017-12-03  NaN NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
6       2153216 2018-02-01  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
7       2154339 2018-02-10  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
8       2160331 2017-12-31  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
9       2181362 2018-03-20  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
...         ...        ...  ...  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ...  ..  ...
22345   3148657 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
22346   3148662 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0
22347   3148688 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
22348   3148695 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
22349   3148705 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
22350   3148743 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
22351   3148755 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
22352   3148757 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
22353   3148764 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
22354   3148794 2018-03-30  1.0 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN

[22355 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: Сейчас проверю. Чтобы я без вас, как всегда, делал!
)

Comment: получил ошибку ValueError: Grouper for 'type' not 1-dimensional

Comment: @Ste_kd, можете привести __воспроизводимый__ пример данных? Для указанных в вопросе данных решение работает правильно ;)

Comment: там данные с работы, не могу выкладывать. Сначала ошибку формата дат или вроде того выдавало, я в обеих таблицах поправил
`a.date = pd.to_datetime(a.date)` и после этого not 1 dimensional выдало

Comment: Прикрепил ссылку на таблицы

Comment: @при попытке объединить эти два DF по полям `Idclient`, `Dateinput` - я получаю пустое множество...

Comment: Возможно это из за точного времени? время в обоих DF отличаются, могут совпадать непосредственно только даты.

Comment: а почему у результирующей таблицы строк меньше вышло чем у исходной?
исходный размер df  'a' - (22355, 2)
результирующий df  -  (21401, 10)

Comment: а почему они должны совпадать??

Comment: Потому что подтянуть надо было к df 'a', те сохранить все строки, которые в этой таблице находятся) я по своему написал уже, но вышло не в 1 строку конечно..

Answer (score 0):

`

```
    a.Dateinput = a.Dateinput.dt.floor("D")
    b.Dateinput = b.Dateinput.dt.floor("D")
    result = pd.merge(b, a, on=['Idclient', 'Dateinput'])
    result = result.pivot_table(index='Idclient', columns='i_type', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
    result = result['Dateinput'].reset_index()
    a = a.merge(result, how='left', on='Idclient')

    print(a)



       Idclient  Dateinput    0    1    2    3   10   11  20   30   31   40
 0      2147787 2017-12-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
 1      2149318 2018-03-13  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2      2149963 2018-02-13  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
 3      2150046 2017-12-14  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 4      2150846 2018-01-16  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 5      2152765 2017-12-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 6      2153216 2018-02-01  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
...         ...        ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ...  ...  ...
22345   3148657 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
22346   3148662 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
22347   3148688 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
22348   3148695 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
22349   3148705 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
22350   3148743 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
22351   3148755 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
22352   3148757 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
22353   3148764 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
22354   3148794 2018-03-30  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN

[22355 rows x 12 columns]
```

`